# Google Calendar API calendar id and event id

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, oauth2-playground

I am learning on how to access google calendar API  for creating and  accessing events. I am trying to understand API  using OAuth 2.0 Playground. I am struggling  on what to set for calendarid and eventid

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events/{eventId}
```

Can any one guide me.

Regards,
Sureshkumar Menon

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

calendarId is the email address of your calendar. If you're just using your own, then use the string "primary".

eventId is the ID of the event that you want to modify. If you don't have an event, you should either create one with the 'insert' call, which will include an eventId parameter that you can store and use to modify it later, or use the 'list' call to get a list of events.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing similar issue and got solution to find the calendar event id:

```
->Go to the event debugging URL at https://www.google.com/calendar/render?gsessionid=OK&eventdeb=1.
->Double click to view the affected event.
->Select the drop down menu 'More Actions'.
->Click on the 'Troubleshooting Info'.
->Copy the text that appears and paste it in your reply to support.
```

You can refer the below link which gives details with screen shot
http://googleappstroubleshootinghelp.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-find-troubleshooting-information.html

However i am still looking for a solution to get event ids dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, the debugging URL gives the correct event ID, after providing which my API started working.

Answer (score 0):

i just discover that the list request which retrieves all the event list contains the correct event id. In my web app, i am using fullcalendar, each time i click a event for updated or deleting, the eventclicked method gives a false event id. so, i guess we will have to give a true event id and false event id map stored in our local app. this can be a work around.  but it's liking eating a fly.

Comment: forget the above answer, it's a silly answer. just use the list request to retrieve all the events to your local app, you have event ids with you.