# How to get event ID from Google Calendar page with JavaScript?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-chrome-app

I am creating a Google Chrome extension for Google calendar. I want to get the ID of an event when user visits the event edit page.

How can I get the event ID from the plugin's javascript code  so that I can fire Calendar api v3.0 with that ID.

[image]

**Adding extra info:**
[Google Calendar API calendar id and event id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285795/google-calendar-api-calendar-id-and-event-id)
The comment by @krishna actualy shows how to get the event ID and it works. But how to get the event ID in https://www.google.com/calendar/ URL not in the URL(https://www.google.com/calendar/render?gsessionid=OK&eventdeb=1) as told by Krishna.

Comment: You need to show your research first. I assume you already searched incthe DOM and such.

Comment: I have tried to search in their DOM but only found data-eid. This is not the event ID. Event ID is something different. You can see above image what I found.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's in the `data-eid` attribute that you partially covered in black in the screenshot. It is encoded along with other things as base64 (or base64url).

The following code should decode, extract, and print the event ID (assuming jQuery was loaded):

```
var encoded = $("div.ep[data-eid]").attr("data-eid");
if (encoded !== undefined) {
  var decoded = atob(encoded);
  console.log("Current event ID: " + decoded.split(" ")[0]);
}
```

prints something like:

```
Current event ID: 75v3thapnpd234ocglgk625frc
```